Dubious use of German verb "gehören"
Is this usage of German verb "gehören" correct?

Ihrer Firma  ein Großteil der Satelliten im All."

I'm aware that "gehören" is intransitive verb, thus requires dative object. That's not the question. Rather, the point is whether that sentence's subject is "ein Großteil der Satelliten", requiring singular verb form "gehört", or "Satelliten", requiring plural verb form "gehören".
For example, both "Einer der Satelliten  mir." and "Zwei der Satelliten  mir." are grammatically correct. So I really don't see why the sentence in question here (see above) should be correct.
EDIT: I'd really prefer German-specific answers, and answers by native speakers. (No offence intended.) For example, merely comparing German and English here is unsatisfactory.

Similar questions here and here.

At least the second link doesn't apply to my question, because there the application of a singular verb form of "gehören" to "Anzahl" is   an error, not a grammatical one.)

Concerning the first link, I disagree with applying the linguistic concept of "bridging" here. "bridiging" may be an easy excuse for what may actually be a change in semantics/  perspective: E.g., you can construe a plurality of given things either as a whole, an entirety of things (collectively) or rather individually. You use plural for the latter, and singular for the former

It is technically not correct.
Ignoring that satellites you would definitely say

Ihrer Firma gehört ein Großteil.

It doesn't really matter what majority it is, because the subject doesn't change its number.

Ein Großteil [von was auch immer] gehört der Firma

However, that being said, this is a mistake that can easily happen and that you're likely to get away with.

I would agree with that. Let's wait and see what others may have to say.

I think DUDEN's rule (see below) is due, in part, to giving in to sloppy or maybe anglicized German speech, because DUDEN's problem was, is, and will always be acceptance.

The chapter on "Kongruenz mit dem finiten Verb" (concord with the finite verb) in my Duden grammar (8th edition, rule 1618) states that both singular and plural are correct for "Sammelbezeichnungen" (collective nouns).

"Collective nouns are words such as the following:

Anzahl, Bande, Drittel, Fülle, Gruppe, Hälfte, Handvoll, Haufen, Heer,
Herde, Kreis, Masse, Mehrzahl, Menge, Reigen, Reihe, Schar, Teil, Trupp,
Unmasse, Viertel, Volk, Zahl

If a collective noun in singular goes with an attribute in plural,
the singular (according to the basic grammatical rule) as well as the plural (semantic congruence) are permitted [for the finite verb].
In detail, the semantic content of the collective noun influences the choice of numerus. For words with a vague meaning such as number, abundance, quantity, series, the plural is more common than for others. In addition, the plural of the finite verb is rare when the counted entity is not mentioned."
(my translation and emphasis, based on deepl)

My interpretation is that "Großteil" can be seen as one of these collective nouns as its use is very similar to "Mehrzahl", "Drittel" or "Teil".

I agree, "Großteil", which historically is a contraction of "großer Teil", definitely is collective noun.

"In addition, the plural of the finite verb is rare when the counted entity is not mentioned.". I don't understand… That mean  "Ich sah viele Kinder gestern. Ein Großteil davon waren groß." is rare?

@checkerscheck: yes, they mean you would seldom see "Ein Großteil (davon) waren groß," and mostly "Ein Großteil (davon) war groß."

It's the same rule as in English; since we're talking about multiple satellites the verb requires a plural. In English we'd say "A large proportion of the satellites in space belong to your company." Not "A large proportion of the satellites in space belongs to your company."

No. "Einer der Satelliten  mir." So just stating "We are talking about multiple things." doesn't explain it.

@checkerscheck - in "Einer der Satelliten gehört mir," we're talking about one thing as in English, "One of the satellites belongs to me." Collective nouns (see HalvarF's answer) take a plural verb even if the noun itself is singular: "A lot of the satellites belong to me." "A great many of the satellites belong to me." "A good deal of the satellites belong to me." "A number of the satellites belong to me." "Einer" is not a collective noun since it specifically implies "one".

I expected this objection, and I won't oppose it. That's because your argument here, in favor of “…” is precisely the same why I demand “/ ()…".

“” in German is for use in conjunction with plural subjects (at least plural in form) , as in “Einige/ viele/ zwei/ alle der Satelliten…”.

Note also that "einer" in German doesn't imply "genau einer" ("precisely one"). "Einer" means either "mindestens einer" or "genau einer", and even speaker himself may not be aware of which precisely he means.
